# Examples of a category without duals?

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

This may be a silly question, but are there any examples of categories that *don't* have duals (ie, neither for objects nor arrows)?  I'm currently under the impression that it's impossible to not have a dual category (since for any $\mathcal C$, you can just reverse the arrows to get $\mathcal C^{op}$).

I was reading through a [paper](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/rosetta.pdf) from John Baez & Mike Stay, and on page 5 they give a "chart of concepts" to "help the reader safely navigate the sea of jargon".  I've been making a mind map out of this chart and have been finding examples for each one (eg, the category of sets as an example of Cartesian closed categories, the category of finite-dimensional vector spaces as an example of compact closed categories, etc).

In the process, I realized that the arrows I was drawing for my mind map were necessarily adding more structure (eg, "add 'closed'", "add 'Cartesian'", etc), and a friend pointed out that there's a "forgetful functor" in which each kind of category "forgets" that part of it's structure.

I think a part of my confusion is the issue of "adjunction" and how left adjoints don't guarantee right adjoints (and vice versa) which made me wonder if the idea of duality itself has such a characteristic.

Comment: What *kind* of duals?  As you note, the opposite category always exists.

Comment: Arrow flipping doesn’t make much difference by itself, if you start drawing all the arrows in opposite direction, all axioms for a category will be satisfied, hence $C^{op}$ exists. It gains much more sense in the context of functors though, as we speculate about a functor by saying whether it preserves arrows of reverses them. Speaking about forgetful: there’s a famous theorem stating that there’s no forgetful functor from homotopical category to sets. Just in case if you’re looking for categorical “wonders”, that fact once amazed me a lot(still does).

Comment: @Randall, I think that's what's confusing me; what's actually meant when we take about the "dual of a category"?

Comment: @PeterBalabanov that helps clarify things a bit.  So I take it that $\mathcal C^{op}$ isn't *really* dual (at least, in a way that's interesting or meaningful within category theory)?  But that we are probably more interested in duals of functors themselves?

Comment: I think it's hard to help before you give us an explicit example where your "dual" shows up. There are many notions of duality after all.

Comment: @QiZhu Well, the usual thing that comes to mind when I think of "dual" are the platonic solids (cube/octahedron, icosahedron/dodecahedron, & tetrahedron/tetrahedron).  But I'm not sure this gets in the direction of what a "category without duals" looks like

Comment: I mean it‘s ok that this comes to your mind but that doesn‘t answer the question. As I said, there are many different notions of duality and you have to state which duality you are talking about to get a chance of an useful answer.